# Preinput Form Non Submitable Form Value- HTML

Tags: html

```
<input name="price" id="asdprice" value="" type="text">
```

I do not wish to use any JS if possible

As you can see the value field is empty, and I do not want to prefill it as it will be submitable.

What I want is a prefilled text area, with lets say

```
http://www.
```

as i would like that to be a valid format for that field, normally such filled input will be less opaque.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display a hint for the user to enter a valid URI using an input placeholder attribute:

```
<input name="price" id="adsprice" type="text" placeholder="http://">
```

However the placeholder text will disappear once the field comes into focus. You should be aware that users will enter all kinds of rubbish into form fields, so **always validate the input on the server-side** and prepend the `http://` if it's missing.

BTW, there are valid URIs that do not begin with `http://www.` and not all sites redirect the www. subdomain as you would expect.